# XSLT for-each - Image?

Tags: xslt, umbraco

I have 4 Media Picker items in a document type (SlideImage1, SlideImage2, SlideImage3 and SlideImage4). I would like to be able to show every image out of those 4, so if 1 exists, only show 1, if 2 exists, show 2 etc. If 1, 2, 3, 4 exists then show all of them.

What's the easiest way to check if 2, 3 or 4 exists? About future proofing, is there a way to check if another alias is added (a 5th item) and to automatically add that in?

Is a for-each loop the best way to go about this?

I can currently displaying the images like so, but it doesn't work very well:

```
<xsl:variable name = "SlideImage1" select = "$sharedNode/SlideImage1" />
<xsl:variable name = "SlideImage2" select = "$sharedNode/SlideImage2" />
<xsl:variable name = "SlideImage3" select = "$sharedNode/SlideImage3" />
<xsl:variable name = "SlideImage4" select = "$sharedNode/SlideImage4" />        

<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="$SlideImage1 !='' and $SlideImage2 !='' and $SlideImage3 !='' and $SlideImage4 !=''">
    <div class="projectSlide">  
        <p><img src="{umbraco.library:GetMedia($SlideImage1, 0)/umbracoFile}" height="240" width="280" /></p>
        <p><img src="{umbraco.library:GetMedia($SlideImage2, 0)/umbracoFile}" height="240" width="280" /></p>
        <p><img src="{umbraco.library:GetMedia($SlideImage3, 0)/umbracoFile}" height="240" width="280" /></p>
        <p><img src="{umbraco.library:GetMedia($SlideImage4, 0)/umbracoFile}" height="240" width="280" /></p>
    </div>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:if test="$SlideImage1 !=''">
      <xsl:variable name = "SlideImagePath1" select="umbraco.library:GetMedia($SlideImage1, 0)/umbracoFile" />
      <img src="{$SlideImagePath1}" height="240" width="280"/>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need any loops to do this.

```
<xsl:template match="whatever">
  <div class="projectSlide">  
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$sharedNode/*[starts-with(name(), 'SlideImage')]" />
  </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(), 'SlideImage')]">
  <xsl:variable name="img" select="umbraco.library:GetMedia(., 0)" />
  <p><img src="{$img/umbracoFile}" height="240" width="280" /></p>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: In your example you only used SlideImage1, but what about 2, 3 and 4? Is there a way to insert them into the img variable too?

Comment: @Madness Sorry, copy/paste mistake on my end. Of course you want to pass the current node (`.`) to `GetMedia()`.

Comment: That makes sense :) The last thing is having to use the $sharedNode variable in the GetMedia() method also, as this is how "shared" images are actually being called in.

Comment: It's ok figured it out :) Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @Madness Good to hear! :)

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to answer in detail if you gave example input and output, but here’s a template that would match elements like `<SlideImageN/>`:

```
<xsl:template match="//*[starts-with(name(), 'SlideImage')]">
  <whatever-you-want-to-output/>
</xsl:template>
```

You could also use `for-each`, depends how declarative vs. imperative you want your stylesheet to be.

Comment: FYI, a match expression does not need to be "fully qualified". `match="*[starts-with(name(), 'SlideImage')]"` is enough.